# Service worker 'sync' event doesn't work on IOS, how to store offline data into indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline, indexeddb

I am trying to build an offline site version for PWA and stuck with a problem.
Service worker 'sync' event works great on Android and desktop but doesn't work on IOS. 
My code init here.

```
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('${appDns!}/serviceWorker.js?v=${appVersion!}')
                    .then(function() {
                        return navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                    })
                    .then(function (registration) {
                        if (registration.sync) {
                            registration.sync.register('offline-sync')
                                    .then(function () {
                                    })
                                    .catch(function (err) {
                                        console.error('Service workers sync problem.', err);

                                    });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.info('Service workers "register" is not supported.');
                        return err;
                    });
}
```

but on IOS `registration` doesn't have `sync` and method `sync` in service worker doesn't fire

```
    self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
        console.log('SYNC!!!!!!!!!! event:', event);
        return event.waitUntil(syncDataForOffline().catch(e => console.error("syncDataForOffline: ", e)));
    });
```

**Perhaps someone knows workaround how to store data into indexedBD for IOS.**

.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [`workbox-background-sync`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync).

On browsers that support the Background Sync API natively, it will use that. On browsers that don't have native support, it will automatically attempt to replay queued requests each time the service worker thread starts up.

In both cases, it uses IndexedDB "under the hood" to store a serialized version of the failed `Request`.

Comment: Could I ask you how do you support 'sync event' back compatibility under the hood , which event do you use for store data into IDB?

Comment: You end up listening for rejections when making a `fetch()` for the `POST`/`PUT` and use that as the signal to write to IndexedDB. And then you read from IndexedDB each time the service worker starts up to see if there's anything that needs to be replayed.